# is there a table with max stats for all weapons?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am playing Diablo 3 and find it quite hard to distinguish good items from bad items.

Is there a table where i can see, where the max values of the items are listed?

I would then keep everything that has at least 80% of the max values.

Comment: not a horrible idea.

Answer (score 7):

There are too many max stats on all the gears to list, but [this website](http://www.d3maxstats.com/) has a good interactive GUI that shows you all of them (including legendaries).

Here is a c/p example for just weapons:

> One-Handed Melee
>   **Primary**
>   Dexterity+400 (Devil Tongue)
>   Dexterity+350
>   Intelligence+400 (Devil Tongue)
>   Intelligence+350
>   Strength+400 (Devil Tongue)
>   Strength+350
>   Vitality+400 (Devil Tongue)
>   Vitality+350
>   **Offense**
>   Attack Speed+21% (Azurewrath)
>   Attack Speed+11%
>   Attacks per Second+0.25 (Echoing Fury)
>   Attacks per Second+0.17 (The Ancient Bonesaber of Zumakalis)
>   Cold Damage+458
>   Critical Hit Chance+1% (Sever)
>   Critical Hit Chance+1% (Born's Searing Spite)
>   Critical Hit Chance+1% (Kill)
>   Critical Hit Chance+1% (Flesh Tearer)
>   Critical Hit Chance+1% (Nutcracker)
>   Critical Hit Damage+100%
>   Damage+50%
>   Damage against Elites+10% (Sun Keeper)
>   Damage against Elites+6%
>   Elemental Damage+727
>   Maximum Damage+411
>   Minimum Damage+316
>   **Defense**
>   Block Chance+7% (Doombringer)
>   Thorns+811 (Nailbiter)
>   **Resistance**
>   Cold Resistance+20 (The Wedge)
>   Fire Resistance+50 (The Burning Axe of Sankis)
>   Resistance to All+80 (Empyrean Messenger)
>   Resistance to All+80 (Wizardspike)
>   **Life**
>   Life per Hit+959
>   Life per Kill+2878
>   Life per Second+599 (Sky Splitter)
>   Life Steal+3%
>   **Resource**
>   Life per Fury Spent+20 (Blade of the Warlord)
>   Max Fury+15
>   **Adventure**
>   Bonus Experience+24
>   Magic Find+45% (Sun Keeper)
>   Reduced Level Req.+18
>   Sockets+1
>   Chance On Hit
>   Chance to Blind+2.6%
>   Chance to Chill+2.6%
>   Chance to Fear+20% (Echoing Fury)
>   Chance to Fear+2.6%
>   Chance to Freeze+15% (Azurewrath)
>   Chance to Freeze+2.6%
>   Chance to Immobilize+2.6%
>   Chance to infl. Bleed+35%
>   Chance to Knockback+2.6%
>   Chance to Slow+2.6%
>   Chance to Stun+2.6%